# Server error when sorting array using java script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am collecting service data from a day care organisation in a Google Spreadsheet with 13 columns and up to 10-12000 rows.

To create a weekly service report I am fetching the entire table into an array by the following statements:

```
//Fetch all required data and pack it into an array
  var DataRange = Konsoblatt.getRange(StartRow, 1, NumRows, ColumnEmailAddressTageseltern)   //Define required data range: all rows and columns up to the email address of the parents
  var AlleEintraege = DataRange.getValues();   //Fetch all data in defined range
```

That always works perfectly.

To compile the report I need to sort the fetched data along the service dates using:

```
AlleEintraege.sort(ArraySort(ColumnDatumLeistung-1)); //Sort array for the date of the service
```

Which refers to:

```
function ArraySort(column) {
//Diese Funktion sortiert ein Array nach der Kolonne "column"
  return function (a,b) {
    a = a[column];
    b = b[column];
    return a == b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1)
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Independent of the size of the Spreadsheet this works normally well, but from time to time results in a "Server error" without more detailed description.

I first thought that I might have invalid dates in the spreadsheet but did not find any so far.
When this server errors occurs, all I need to do is sorting the Spreadsheet manually by the Service dates and then the above function works without any error.

I am not really experienced in sorting algorithms and copied the above example for examples in the internet.

Any idea on why I run into that problem from time to time?

Thanks a lot

Heinz

Comment: The server error does not appear to be related to your algorithm. Can you have a fixed set of data (in another spreadsheet) and run the same function as a trigger for every 5 minutes or so for a full day. That will give you an idea whether the problem is with your algorithm or the server.

Comment: In a separate spreadsheet you can also run the spreadsheet function: = sort(importrange("Id_of_remote_sheet", "range"),13,1) where range is the sheet and range of the remote sheet e.g. Sheet4!A:M  if you want to sort on the tenth column, or example, change the 13 to a 10.  The final 1 can be a 0 (zero) for descending or ascending sort.

Comment: @Srik This script is already based on a trigger and runs weekly since more than a year now. As I said: It normally runs well, but every 2-3 months the reports do not get out automatically...

So, yes I also do not think it is a script error. But why does it happen sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

This error happened with me recently too. And I worked-around it by parsing all the data to the same type before I sorted. It seems that there's a situation where comparing a string to a number or vice-verse triggers the issue.

Comment: Hello Henrique,
Thanks for your feedback. Good to know I am not the only one :-) Not sure what you mean by "parsing all the data to the same type". I am sorting along dates. So it is always the same type.

However, can it be that sometimes day is not fully considered as a date and in this case the sort fails?

I already thought about that as well, but if that is the case, why does it then work, when I am manually sorting the spreadsheet along dates and then re-run the script?

Comment: Hello Henrique,
Thanks for your feedback. Good to know I am not the only one :-) Not sure what you mean by "parsing all the data to the same type". I am sorting along dates. So it is always the same type.

However, can it be that sometimes day is not fully considered as a date and in this case the sort fails?

I already thought about that as well, but if that is the case, why does it then work, when I am manually sorting the spreadsheet along dates and then re-run the script?

How could I debug the script to find out on what line in the spreadsheet it happens?

Thanks a lot

Heinz

Comment: In my case I was sorting strings, but some cells had numbers in it, then I just looped through the array once first parsing everything to string `value+''`. I guess you could verify that it's all dates first and set a zero date for blank values, or you could parse it all to string or number, which suit you best. Or even write a better sort function that checks the types before comparing, since `a < b` does not make much sense for different types.